# Best solution to audit and time log user behavior in react webapp?

Tags: reactjs, logging, analytics, tracking

What are the available libs / tools to monitor user behavior in a react webapp?

I working with an advanced web system and have come to a point where it is important to collect data on user behavior on specific parts of the webapp. Example I would like to track how much time each user spend on the profile time the fist time they visit it. I would also like to log this in my database so I can do statistics and compare previous statistic.

Tool must:

- Work inside a react app.
- Be able to track time from component is visible until it is not visible.
- Track time spend on a single page.
- Be a independent standalone tool, no third party cloud jazz.

I'm not looking for:

- google analytics.
- tools that show where users clicked
- tools that request user feedback
- cookie tools

Answer (score 2):

About two years later we found this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/timeme which does almost exactly the described needs.

We use it in react like this:

```
const TimeMe = require('timeme.js');

getInitialState () {
  return {
    entryTime: new Date()
  };
},

componentDidMount () {
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.loggingInteraction);
  TimeMe.startTimer(pageId);
},

async loggingInteraction () {
  TimeMe.stopTimer(pageId);
  const activeTimeOnPage = TimeMe.getTimeOnPageInSeconds(pageId) * 1000;
  TimeMe.resetRecordedPageTime(pageId);
  const totalTimeOnPage = T.millisecondsBetween(this.state.entryTime, T.now());
  // http send time on page request
},
```